# Is every continuous function that preserves (ir)rationality a rational function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a, b]\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that for all $r\in\mathbb R$, $f(r)$ is rational iff $r$ is rational. Does it follow that $f$ is a rational function?

Comment: Do you consider $f(x)=|x|$ a rational function?

Comment: This might help : [Please click here][1]


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48910/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I missed the "iff" in the original question. As such, the answer below is not correct, it provides examples of functions where $f(r)$ is rational if $r$ is rational, but not necessarily only for rational $r$. Piecewise linear functions still work, though, for more complicated examples see [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48910/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational)

---

It does not have to be, any continuous and piecewise rational function with rational coefficients will do this, too. And there are even weirder functions, using very non-explicit constructions. E.g., Cantor showed that any densely ordered countable set without endpoints has the order type of the rationals. So if you take any dense subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, there is a strictly increasing homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q} \to S$ which extends by continuity to a homeomorphism of the real line to itself which maps rational numbers to rational numbers. By choosing $S$ in weird ways, you can make sure that $f$ is not a rational function on any interval.

Comment: It isn't true that rational functions always work, e.g., $x^2$.

Comment: Rational functions with rational coefficients do work, but these constructions show that there are many more examples.

Comment: $x^2$ is a rational function with rational coefficients.  It sends some irrational numbers to rational numbers.

Comment: Of course you are right, I completely misunderstood the comment.